# Converting a sum into $\Sigma$ notation

Tags: formatting, summation

I have a simple expression of the form

$\quad \quad t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1$

and I want *Mathematica* to convert this to the form

$\quad \quad \sum _{i=0}^5 t^i$

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you give more examples and explain in more detail what sorts of input expressions are possible?

Comment: Simple Algebraic expression of the general form $\sum _{i=1}^n \alpha  t^i$

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?:

```
expr = -t^Range[0, 5] // Total

toΣ[expr_Plus] := 
 Block[{n}, 
  HoldForm[Sum[#, {n, #2}]] & @@ {FindSequenceFunction[List @@ expr, n], Length@expr}]

toΣ@expr
```

[image]

If you want to manually set the initial index:

```
toΣ[expr_Plus, init_Integer: 1] := 
 Block[{n, l = Length@expr}, 
  HoldForm[Sum[#, {n, init, #2}]] & @@ 
  {FindSequenceFunction[{Range[init, l - 1 + init], List @@ expr}\[Transpose], n], l}]

toΣ[expr, 0]
```

[image]